# Python Envoy won't run threaded

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to launch this command from python in a background thread while keeping the main program thread running using [envoy](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy):

```
envoy.run('python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9999')
```

This works but hangs, it doesn't run threaded as it should do, so that I can't kill it afterwards when I'm done. I tried to wrap it into a Thread:

```
class FileServerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.process = None

    def run(self):
        self.process = envoy.run('python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9999')        

    def kill(self):
        self.process.kill
```

but again, this doesn't work because self.process is never assigned (since envoy.run doesn't end and never returns).

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that you can't do it with `run`, but you can do it by `connect`.

```
import envoy
p = envoy.connect("python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9999")
print "run here!"
p.kill()
```

however, after `kill()`, I found that the process became a zombie, `p.block()` will solve it.